# How to create a bug automatically in DevOps when the automated test fails in Azure Test Plans

Tags: azure, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running my Selenium tests from Azure Test Plans in DevOps. When any of my test fails, I have the option in DevOps to create a bug for it**(attaching the screenshot of the option to create a bug manually once the test case fails)** but I want the bug to be created automatically as soon as the test case fails. Is there a way to configure it so that my work item(bug) gets created automatically?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to [create a work item on failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops) in build pipeline as below, so you could enable it to create a bug when this build is failed.
[image]

In addition, if you run test plan in release pipeline, this option is not available in release pipeline, so you need to use API to create a work item in it. You could use [Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to run Rest API: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to create a work.

Set the condition

[image]

Or you could directly use this Extension- [Create Bug on Release failure](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmanBedi18.CreateBugTask).

Comment: I used the extension and it worked but I would have wanted the bug to be created against the test case which has failed. Also, can the description of the bug be configured before running the task in the release pipeline? Thanks

Comment: If you use Powershell Task to run Rest API: Work Items - Create to create a bug, you could specify its ```Description``` field like other fields ```Title```.  Sample body looks like ```[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample bug"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "from": null,
    "value": "test"
  }
]```. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547568/how-to-create-work-item-on-failure-in-azure-release-pipeline-not-build-pipeline for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For the YAML pipeline, you can use the *CreateBug* task:

[image]

Example task:

```
- task: CreateBug@2
  inputs:
    isyamlpipeline: true
    custompaths: false
    customrequestor: false
```

Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmanBedi18.CreateBugTask