# Add attachment from test run when creating a Bug ticket in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, attachment

So what I am trying to do is to create a Bug ticket after a test run fails in DevOps. I have a screenshot in my Attachments area but when I try to create a Bug ticket only error messages, the stack trace and other kinds of information is automatically displayed in the Repro Steps of the Bug.

When I create the Bug ticket I also want the screenshot to be included in it to be previewed but the Attachment tab of the Bug ticket is empty.

Is there a way to add it there? Or anywhere else (bug, test run, etc) so It can be previewed? Right now, from the test run the screenshot can only be downloaded or deleted; the option for preview is disabled.

[image: Preview not available]

Repro Steps:

1. Write an automated test (with SetUp, TearDown <- Screenshot is taken from here, etc)
2. Right-click the test from the "Test Explorer" and then click "Associate to Test Case"; add the test case ID and save.
3. Push the code to the repo.
4. Build the pipeline in DevOps based on the new code.
5. Go to the "Test Suite" that has that test case and in "Define" tab, execute one test with "Run with options".
6. From there select test type and runner with the option "Automated tests using release stage".
7. From the same window select a build, the release pipeline and stage then click "Run".
8. After the execution is complete, double click the test case and then the latest outcome.
9. You are redirected to that specific test run.
10. The "Attachments" tab has one item within (because the test failed and the trigger from the TearDown).But it cannot be previewed.
11. From above "Summary" you can create a bug for this, prepopulating Retro Steps with the information I mentioned in the comments.
    Howerver, for this Bug item the "Attachments" tab is empty. So it does not take the file from the test run.

This is the code for creating a screenshot (present in TearDown method):

```
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
{
    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Page.GetDriver()).GetScreenshot();
    string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.fffff}.png";
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(path, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

    TestContext.AddTestAttachment(path);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code trials, and more information about how the tests are being executed.

Comment: I added more details in the comment section of the answer below but I added a picture to the question, if that's ok.

Comment: What code have you tried? Please include a [repro].

Comment: I added the code related to the screenshot in the description, other than that I don't think that there is any more piece of code that is relevant because everything other than linking to the test case is done in DevOps. The reproductible example is in the comments of the answer below; that is exactly what I've done.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you are using to create the Bug work item.

Comment: I am trying to create the Bug item manually. Basically when I'm in a test run I have a dropdown "Bug", and the first option "Create bug". And if i choose to create it from there, the Repro Steps section is prepopulated with all the information from the test run (priority, machine, error message, etc).

Comment: I am still unclear what procedure you are using to do this. Can you clarify? It might sound silly, but literally, please include a numbered list of the steps you are doing up to the point where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you are doing...

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Include this as plain text in your question.

Comment: Another similar question with no answer: [Insert test case attachments into a bug ticket in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72638302/3092298).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no supported function to preview screenshots in the test run at present. You may submit a suggestion at website:[feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21)

But when i test in my Test plans, i find a workaround to add screenshot and preview it.

1 use the web runner to take screenshots of the web app while testing.
[image: Capture Screenshot]

2 Create bug. The steps and your comments and screenshots are automatically added to the bug.And you can see the screenshot in your bug detail.
[image: Bug ticket]

3 click the screenshot and drag it manually, you'll see `upload file UI` .After uploading, you can preview screenshots in Attachment Tab in your new bug.
[image: Preview attachment]

Comment: The thing is that I make screenshots using Selenium and NUnit for automated tests and they just appear in the Attachments tab of the test run. What I want to do is to just see it somewhere in DevOps without downloading it. Basically I don't and the screenshot to one of the test steps; I don't know if you can do that with Selenium tho..

Comment: Could you provide detailed information about  how the tests are being executed? used in pipeline or other？

Comment: Ok so I wrote some automated tests with Selenium and NUnit and I linked them with the test cases from DevOps (I created the test cases there and then, through Visual Studio I added an association between the code and the test cases from DevOps). In DevOps I have a pipeline (also a repo ofc) that I use to execute all of my tests at specific hours; but I can also use it to execute the tests one by one or a group of them from Test Plans. After the execution, I can a Test Run that displays the result. The thing is that I want to attach a screenshot to that Test Run when it fails.

Comment: And that screenshot needs to be previewed from there (so without being downloaded). I did that part in my code (using Screenshot object, calling SaveAsFile, etc) and indeed in the test run I can see the file in the Attachment tab, but I can only download or delete it. The option "Preview" is disabled (I tried changing the format of the image but it is the same). So what I want is either being able to preview to screenshot from there or somehow adding it automatically to a Bug ticket's attachments when creating it from the same page with the Test Run.

Comment: Basically, the execution of the test is done automatically from the Test Plans, as I said. The steps that I'm doing are the following: click "Run with options" for a test case, I set "Select test type and runner" to "Automated tests using release stage", add a build (from the pipeline), select the release pipeline and the stage, and then run.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [How to create a bug automatically in DevOps when the automated test fails in Azure Test Plans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66955159/3092298). I'm not sure if that will fully address your problem, though.

Alternately you can create a bug work item in C# when the test fails: [Create a bug in Azure DevOps Services using .NET client libraries](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/create-a-work-item-bug-on-failure-of-specific-test/651799).

---

When you create a bug based on a failing test, the "Links" tab of the new bug links to the failed test as a "Test Result" link.

You can click the link to the test result, which gives you access to the screenshot. It isn't the ideal solution, but there is a way to trace back from the bug to the screenshot.

So the general process is:

1. Go to the failed release or build.
2. Go to the logs for that release.
3. Switch to the "Tests" tab.
4. Choose the failing test in the list.
5. Click the "Bug" action menu item above the list of tests, and choose "Create bug".

   [image]
6. Switch to the "Links" tab on the new bug work item. You should see a "Test Result" link to the failing test.

There doesn't appear to be an automated way of linking the attachment, as Dou Xu-MSFT said, but there is at least traceability. In the meantime we could call this a "training issue".

Comment: Even in this case, at step 6 the "Attachments" tab on the new bug is still empty. The "Test Result" link you are mentioning in probably the one from the "Links" tab. Indeed it redirects me to the test run. But the screenshot still needs to be downloaded to be seen, and I cannot preview it.

Comment: @RobertGabriel: you are correct. I mean the "Links" tab, not the attachments tab. I understand that this doesn't get you exactly what you want. My answer is a workaround. What you want doesn't appear possible unless you want to create the bug work item in C# using the Azure DevOps REST API.

Comment: I understand, so it is not possible to do this. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: If it helps you, you could also accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.